# VB6 COM Object not working on IIS 7 Windows 2008 x64

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, vb6

I am extremely new to building webs and using IIS 7 and I have been charged with migrating some classic ASP sites in or DEV environment. My question is, and I apologize if I word it incorrectly, why don't any VB6 COM objects work? I have a site that uses a COM object for a sign-in process and it seems to do nothing and generates no log file. The site with the login is classic ASP, which I have working, but when you go to submit during login - nothing.

Does anyone have a guide or site I could reference? I've tried enabling ASP debuging to the page and whatnot in the ASP section of IIS Manager but nothing.

Thanks.

EDIT: I still have not resolved this issue. I resorted to re-writing the vb COM object into ASP and am going to try that as a work-around.

Comment: I just rewrote the object in .NET since I could not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you need to allow your application pool to run 32-bit applications. The way to do this is to right click your app pool, click Advanced Settings and change the "Enable 32 bit applications" setting to True.

Comment: @MattB - I checked and I do have Enable 32-bit Applications set to True and I am running in Classic for the Managed Pipeline Mode. Any other suggestions?